# Webscraping coordinates of a polygon with Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape information from this webpage and many similar, https://knowyourcity.info/settlement/1846/5119249

When viewing the page source the coordinates for the polygon at the top of the page are available but not when inspecting the polygon element. Would anyone know how to scrape these coordinates into a column of a dataframe using BeautifulSoup package in python?

This is the code I used to access the website

```
from requests import get
url = 'http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/1846/5119249'
response = get(url)
print(response.text[:500])
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
type(html_soup)
```

Comment: Do you want to get this information from the page: `[["5.599769999885609","-0.224459999729163"],["5.599920830581937","-0.2235293057328249"] ...`?

Comment: Yes that's right!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the map is driven by the variable settlement. Therefore one option
is to loop through all the `scripts` tags and search for `var settlement`. Once you've found the variable, use simple find and subscribing to get the variable data. Convert this to json and then return the boundaries.

The example is for illustration purposes. You'll most likely want to refactor the code:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

def getHtml():
    url = 'http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/1846/5119249'
    response = get(url)
    return response.text

def extractBoundaries(html):
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    scripts = html_soup.find_all('script')
    
    for script in scripts:
        startFind = "var settlement = "
        endFind = "};"

        if script.contents and startFind in script.contents[0]:
            scriptText = script.contents[0]
            startIndex = scriptText.find(startFind) + len(startFind)
            endIndex = scriptText.find(endFind) + len(endFind) -1
            settlementData = scriptText[startIndex:endIndex]
            jsonData = json.loads(settlementData)
            return jsonData['verification/A0_Boundary']

html = getHtml()
results = extractBoundaries(html)
print(results)
```

**Output:**

```
5.599769999885609 -0.224459999729163 0 0;5.599920830581937 -0.2235293057328249 0 0;5.600343984087658 -0.2220772405721618 0 0;5.600582171330188 -0.2212706242398781 0 0;5.600757735181389 -0.2203650797845285 0 0;5.600943331869303 -0.2195227513738018 0 0;5.601229999764712 -0.2178069995933356 0 0;5.601684627743396 -0.2160719483616731 0 0;5.602178000314495 -0.215115999603654 0 0;5.60277082980997 -0.213977987593978 0 0;5.60322584449716 -0.2131045282513355 0 0;5.603939996133988 -0.2117290691411995 0 0;5.604261867990886 -0.2111080629866819 0 0;5.604746000027944 -0.210174000129939 0 0;5.605512212518647 -0.208745954062465 0 0;5.605957084651777 -0.2079168151088879 0 0;5.60642700020594 -0.2070410004417909 0 0;5.606837000227415 -0.2063009995914058 0 0;5.607503034537444 -0.2072989224072899 0 0;5.608332999968013 -0.2085879998362543 0 0;5.608940827457275 -0.2094694811315776 0 0;5.609384837140567 -0.2101133921192968 0 0;5.609949999892649 -0.210933000057878 0 0;5.610520744736618 -0.2114266172445696 0 0;5.61105999981919 -0.2118930002616821 0 0;5.612419000436546 -0.2126160003281257 0 0;5.613144659798252 -0.2126897915006225 0 0;5.614907000058054 -0.2128690003040674 0 0;5.615398000217567 -0.2144450001366067 0 0;5.615173904452149 -0.2159211302559356 0 0;5.614935501372315 -0.2174915048290131 0 0;5.61470415976919 -0.2190153628686744 0 0;5.614495076386731 -0.2203926071330784 0 0;5.61425499966856 -0.2219740001999071 0 0;5.613865981729703 -0.2233052558328268 0 0;5.613273865396593 -0.2253315354219581 0 0;5.612689000297166 -0.227333000017893 0 0;5.611838309990048 -0.2274067552175438 0 0;5.611219650166788 -0.2272163984180224 0 0;5.610458222968646 -0.2271212195685735 0 0;5.609547010985807 -0.2272079061199293 0 0;5.608730734136145 -0.2266937097468826 0 0;5.607481517358167 -0.2262178181977106 0 0;5.605377060602905 -0.2259990644052436 0 0;5.603420000032998 -0.2258499999774699 0 0;5.602499999875136 -0.2257000002547329 0 0;5.601491149397077 -0.225320574484897 0 0;5.599769999885609 -0.224459999729163 0 0
```

Comment: This is very useful thank you very much! I want to create a loop through multiple settlements for this. When the settlement varies the last digit of the URL changes but they don't go up in integers, they seem to be slightly random numbers. Can I create a list and populate it with strings such as: 

settlement = [str(i) for i in list(5119249, 5193260, 9015532 , .....)]

or is there a more efficient way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the URL I'm guessing the first ID is the city and the second is Settlement ID (which is increment based on all countries/ city). I think the best approach to fetching the URL is to scrape the search page for URL (and increment pageId number) e.g https://knowyourcity.info/explore-our-data/country/?country=ghana&pagenum=1

Comment: Ok thank you, sorry what do you mean by scrape the search page for URL? I can't see how they increment overall. Thanks!!

Comment: knowyourcity.info/explore-our-data/country/?country=ghana&pagenum=1 - The "View data" contains a href to the settlement data. This will be better than trying to guess the URL through incrementing a number